# Rolling Sum in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I am trying to create a rolling twelve month sum in excel using vb. The last column with data is dynamic so I created a variable to store that column number each time. I then tried to create a loop that would output the sum of the previous 12 cells and move to the next cell until it reached 12 calculation cells. But this is not working... Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong?? Thanks!

```
Sub OSR_ReportComplete()
 Dim lCol As Long
 Dim p As Integer
 lCol = Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 For p = 0 To 12
    Range(Cells(15, lCol - p)).Value = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(7, lCol - 
     p), Cells(7, lCol - p - 12)))
 Next p
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably not the problem here, but you should always specify the worksheet when using ranges...

Comment: Not working, is not a good description of the problem.  What error do you get or what is it doing that it should not?

Comment: I only posted the snippet of code that I added to complete the rolling sum. This code is in a loop that loops thru the worksheets and performs several tasks. The rest of the code works fine, but when I add the code I posted it does not do anything different. I would have expected a group of cells in row 15 that have sums, but I do not get anything.

Comment: What is the ActiveSheet when you execute this part of the code? That is why you should always specify the worksheet.

Comment: `Range(Cells(15, lCol - p)).Value` should throw an error, my guess is you have a `On Error Resume Next` that forces it to skip that line completely.

Comment: Change the `Range(Cells(15, lCol - p)).Value` to `Cells(15, lCol - p).Value`

Comment: Whats your `lCol` evaluating to? If it's less then 25 this `Cells(7, lCol - p - 12)` will cause an error

Comment: Okay thanks, I do have a On Error Resume Next... Let me try that fix

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` should be used very rarely.  And it should be followed up with `On Error Goto 0` shortly after to reset the error handling, or you miss why your code is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be done in a neater way but this works

```
Sub OSR_ReportComplete()
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim p As Integer
    lCol = Cells(7, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For p = 0 To 12
       Cells(15, lCol - p) = Application.Sum(Range(Cells(7, lCol - p), Cells(7, lCol - p - 12)))
    Next p
End Sub
```

Also, If your lCol evaluates to a value less then 25 it will fall over though due to trying to reference a column less than 1. I'd recommend using `Offset` instead

However, a rolling total can be done very easily in excel formulas also. Say your first value is in Column `A` and your date is in row `1`, in row `2` enter in Column `A` `=SUM($A$1:A1)` and drag along the rest of your range

Giving:

[image: Results]

Formulas:
[image: Formulas]

The following code will generate the formulas above for row 1 in one line instead of doing your loop. This is an example as I don't understand the layout of your sheet from your code

```
Sub OSR_ReportComplete2()
    With Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
        .Offset(1, 0).Formula = "=SUM(" & .Cells(1).Address & ":" & Split(.Cells.Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False), ":")(0) & ")"
    End With
End Sub
```

This is easier to write in R1C1 notation (however will be displayed in A1 in Excel Sheet)

```
Sub OSR_ReportComplete2()
    With Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
        .Offset(1, 0).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(" & .Cells(1).Address(ReferenceStyle:=False) & ":R[-1]C)"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay thanks, the issue is that my data generates from a SQL database so I want to run my analysis automatically after the data comes over and it is not always in the same location or else I would just use a simple formula

Comment: Did your amended code do the job then? Also you could program to fill the cells with the formulas as opposed to the values

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I suggest you don't use VBA for this. Instead, use the inbuilt OFFSET function, like this.
[image: I have used width argument in the offset but one canuse height for a diff direction]

Your code is quite complex, but maybe you should be using xlToRight instead of xlToLeft to find the last column.

If you want to use VBA, you can try using WorkSheetFunction.offset, putting it into a range variable and then summing that range.

Comment: `xlToRight` might miss the last column in OPs range if there is an empty cell. Hence the use of `xlToLeft`